# How can we prove that the square root of any number is equal to the statment given below

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Is there any theorem that can explain this    $\sqrt[n]{x}= x^{1/n} $, is there any practical example of $ x^{1/n} $, 1/n times of a number.

Comment: How are you defining each side of the equality?

Comment: That's not a theorem. It's the definition of $x^{1/n}$. That's what it has to be if you want rules like $x^{a+b}=x^ax^b$ to work for rational exponents as it does for integer exponents.

Comment: @user127219: could you upvote (click on "arrow up") the answers you find useful and pick the one that answers your question, if there is any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equality is the definition of the root of power $n$.

To compute such values for $x > 0$, use $x^{1/n} = \exp\left(\frac{\ln x}{n}\right)$ - this is how computers do it, it works for $\forall x > 0, \forall n \in (\mathbb{R}\setminus{0})$

A practical example is the interest on a saving account. Say, a bank pays $2\%$ per year interest rate. How would you compute an interest that accrues in a month? If you compute the interest as $\frac{2\%}{12}$ (there are 12 months in a year, assume that we have to pay the same interest each month), then the yearly interest will be $\left(1+\frac{0.02}{12}\right)^{12} - 1 > 0.02$. 
Correct interest computation will be $\left(1+0.02\right)^{\frac{1}{12}} - 1$.

Comment: How is that calculation easier than taking the $n$-th root directly? What you're suggesting will often turn out to be $e$ raised to an irrational power.

Comment: This is how computers calculate such values, actually.

Comment: Probably because you'd only need two tables, instead of one table for each possible root. I still believe $n$-th roots are easier to _calculate_ than first a logarithm and then an irrational power.

Comment: I believe computers use Taylor series to compute exponentials and logarithms, there cannot be any tables, because there are too many rational numbers :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this  [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/724426/181067) which shows that $$\sqrt[b]{x^a}=x^ {a/b}$$ and so your question asks about the particular case of $a=1$

(In fact the answer referenced to begins by defining $x^{1/b}$ then building up to $x^{a/b}$)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a *very* practical example of a use of $x^{1/n}$: tuning a piano.

What we generally perceive as the "interval" between two notes is actually
the ratio of their frequencies.
The ratio of frequencies between middle C and high C (one octave up) on a piano
is exactly $2.$ There are $13$ keys in this interval, producing $12$ smaller
intervals (called half-steps) if you start at middle C and then strike every
key in succession until you reach high C.
In order to make these half-steps all sound uniform, each key is tuned to
a frequency $2^{1/12}$ times the frequency of the key before it.

Comment: Why is that different from using $\sqrt[12]{2}$? It's not clear how this relates to the question at hand.

Comment: It's a good example, but the tempered scale doesn't sound nice. The reason or musical tradition has a twelve-note scale is that the powers of the twelfth root of $2$ are quite close to some rational numbers with small denominators. Those are what sounds nice.

Comment: Yes, it is basically because $\frac{19}{12}$ is a continued fraction term for $\log_2 3$. @Arthur

Comment: @Arthur The equal tuning is a compromise between the ideal ratios we would like to hear and the requirement that we be able to play music in any key. The piano, unlike many other instruments, gives you no way to play a G note a little sharper in one key than in another, so we sacrifice a little bit of the quality of the tonic chord in one key so that the tonic chords in other keys don't sound much worse.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews OP asked for a practical example of $x^{1/n}.$ Since $x^{1/n}$ is $\sqrt[n]{x}$ by definition, it's hard to give an example of one that isn't also an example of the other. It is possible, however, that I misunderstood what OP meant by a "practical example", since OP accepted an answer that simply defined the notation.